# Client side href lost, can I send it back on postback?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm losing client side href. Is it possible to send it back to the server on the button submit using a variable or something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You could use a hidden form input, added on either the server or client side:

```
<input type="hidden" name="referring_url" value="http://...">
```

To automatically add the current URL using JavaScript:

```
<form onsubmit="addHref(this)" ...

function addHref(form) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'hidden';
    input.name = 'referring_url';
    input.value = window.location.href;
    form.appendChild(input);
}
```

Comment: @idelamachine Thanks. But I can't access this on the server side can I?